# There are two cards missing from a deck. Two cards drawn are found to be spades, what is the probability the missing cards are spades?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have tried the following two methods:
1) Found the probability of drawing two spades in each case of 2 spades misssing, 1 spade missing and no spade missing and then used Bayes Theorem

2) Found probability of selecting two spades from a deck from where we have already drawn two spades.

In both the cases I get my answer as 11/245, however the book where the question is given says the answer is 23/206.

Can anyone guide me to my mistake please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume that exactly two cards are drawn, and are done so without replacement, and are seen to both be spades and we ask the probability of the missing cards both being spades.  Imagine then you are drawing two cards from a deck of only $50$ cards which contains all of the usual cards *except* the ace and king of spades.  The probability the first card is a spade is $\frac{11}{50}$ and the second is a spade given that the first is a spade is $\frac{10}{49}$.  Multiplying these, $\frac{11\cdot 10}{50\cdot 49}=\frac{11}{245}$.  This agrees with your answer.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's time to change books then, thanks for clearing my doubt, it's been bugging me for the last half hour. :)

Comment: I cannot think of an interpretation that leads to an answer of $\frac{23}{206}$.  Both the numerator and denominator are particularly strange numbers.  There are $52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49$ equally likely ways in which four cards can be drawn in sequence.  $206$ does not divide evenly into that number, so it does not make sense to have a probability with that denominator appear describing an event in that sample space.  I can only imagine that there is a great deal of missing information, or that the answer was for a different unrelated problem.

Comment: The question asks for the probability of the two missing cards being spades. Surely they went missing when the deck was at $52$ then $51$?

Comment: I respectfully object to the first comment by @JMoravitz. It appears as though the question (in the title) asks us to find the probability of the very event that you have assumed.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 : Isn't it symmetrical? The question could be posed as: If four cards are drawn from a pack, and two are revealed to be spades, what is the probability that the other two are spades?

Comment: @PhilH The probability that the first two cards are both spades given that the third and fourth cards are both spades is exactly the same as the probability that the third and fourth cards are spades given that the first two cards are spades.  There are many problems in probability where it is convenient to change the order in which events have occurred when having done so does not change the actual probabilities of events happening nor their interactions with one another.  It is far easier to visualize the probability if the missing cards go missing after the two cards were drawn.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe The point remains that $206 = 2\cdot 103$, noting that $103$ is prime, cannot be the denominator from any probability question coming from a sample space whose size is a product of numbers all less than or equal to $52$.

Comment: Lol, using WaveX's suggestion, you find the probability that you draw two spades where there is an equal probability that the missing cards are in each of the 10 cases (regarding suit only) gives $\dfrac{103}{1750}$, but that still doesn't seem to yield the book's value for the final probability. But, it does give you a 103 in the denominator.

Comment: there are 6 ways to lose 2 cards not a spade (club,club),(club, heart), (club,diamond),(heart,heart),(heart,diamond),(diamond,diamond) three have 169 ways to choose them, 3 have 156, there are 3 ways to lose exactly one spade (club,spade),(heart,spade),(diamond,spade) each has 169 possibilities.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee For (club,club), there are $\dbinom{13}{2} = 78$ ways to choose them. You were double counting. Note: $\dbinom{39}{2} = 3\cdot \dbinom{13}{2}+3\cdot 13^2$ where there are 39 non-spades, so there are $\dbinom{39}{2}$ ways to choose two of them.

Comment: @JohnBentin - I think you're right. My confusion arose from a combination of my misreading the first attempt as part of the question, and some gaps in the argument presented in the comments!

Comment: okay but my point is the probabilities in each case need to be weighted by the proper cases.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee it is weighted by the proper cases. There are many ways to count the exact same thing. Your method of counting yields the same answer that the OP gets (that is the first method the OP used).

Comment: I was thinking perhaps they don't mean a deck of $52$ cards; also note that the prime factor $103$ is close to $104$, the number of cards in two decks of cards. But the result $\frac{23}{206}$ isn't of the form $\frac{m(m-1)}{n(n-1)}$, which the answer must be, whatever the size of the deck and even if you include jokers. Did you quote the question verbatim? If not, please do so -- sometimes it turns out that a question was misunderstood and paraphrased on the basis of the misunderstanding, and then there's no chance of pointing out the error.

Comment: I have given the question exactly as it is in the book, there is something wrong with the answer in the book or the book itself has not revealed some information, thank you all for your comments.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your explanation. I see what you are saying, there is symmetry between the probabilities of drawing both pairs of cards. It was a little counter-intuitive but I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the question has been answered, correctly, by the asker and in the many comments. Namely, the book is wrong, and the probability is $\frac{11}{245}$. This is my answer too, but it would be redundant to explain it now.